# Username/Email Spam List?

Tags: php, mysql, spam, spam-prevention

I am after a username and email spam list. When a user tries to register I want to check if the username or email they entered is on the username/email spam list and if so mark the account as suspected spam and manually verify membership.

The backend behind it is not my problem, I am just wondering if anyone knows of such spam list(s) that I can import into a MySQL database so I can implement it into my signup script?

I know there is Askimet but believe this is more towards a comments form for example, plus I don't particularly want to send data to a third party to verify if something is potentially spam.

Comment: I suspect that distributing such lists (especially the email list) would run afoul of data protection laws (email addresses are often personally identifiable information) and/or libel laws in various parts of the world.

Comment: You also *need* a third party service if you want to stay up to date. Spam databases are huge and change rapidly.

Comment: There are some spam databases based on IP adresses (not email adresses).

Comment: @Quentin, yes i agree with you, did not think of that to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not spam accounts. Spam email accounts which are used to send out spam are unlikely to be used to sign up for a service.

What you want to use is a Captcha service (such as reCAPTCHA - http://www.google.com/recaptcha/captcha) which will help reduce the chance a bot is attempting to sign up for your site. This is not fool proof, there are many alternative methods (such as hidden ID fields and custom headers) - but it is a start.

Then you want to use an email verification sign up system - which requires the user to actually check their email and click on a verification link, to confirm the email address is real. Otherwise you'll just have people sign up with "Fake@fake.com" and your system wont actually know they are fake...

Comment: Hi, i already have a hidden field to check if it's not been filled in, form token (not for spam purposes), ReCaptcha, used it previously and hate it and Captcha, This was just a thought, i think i will stick with my original idea after reading your advice, where accounts not activated in 48 hours will be deleted, that way anyone who does not activate in 48 hours is potentially spam (unless they was not receiving activation emails), in general i find people who wants to signup activates there accounts immediately or soon after, using this it also saves me time checking through accounts.

Comment: yeah - just delete inactive accounts, and dont let them into the website until they verify and activate their account - this will give you a good level of protection to start from...

Comment: I'll take yours as an accepted answer as you did recommend different solutions, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DNSBL](http://www.dnsbl.info/). It's a service that does what you want. (not sure if you can download their database or you have to query them every time you want to know if it's an adress known for spamming).

Comment: That deals in IP addresses used to send SMTP spam, not usernames or email addresses.

Comment: @dragon112, this is a thirdparty service and is not what i'm looking for but thanks.